# Managing Blank field from Linq Query

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, winforms, linq

I am writing a method in VB.Net that runs a LINQ query on my database, and puts the information from the query into textboxes on a form.

```
Public Sub OpenPartWindow(ByVal partNumber As String)
    Using dbContext As New DB_LINQDataContext
        Dim query = (From p In dbContext.Parts
                     Join ppl In dbContext.Part_Price_Logs On p.Part_ID Equals ppl.Part_ID
                     Where p.Part_Number = partNumber
                     Select p.Part_Number, p.Part_Description, p.Part_Information, p.Supplier.Supplier_Name, _
                     p.Part_Manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name, p.Part_Subcategory.Part_Category.Category_Description, _
                     p.Part_Subcategory.Subcategory_Description, ppl.Cost_Per_Unit, ppl.Discount_Percentage).First()
        MessageBox.Show(query.ToString())
        txtPartNum.Text = query.Part_Number.ToString()
        txtSupplier.Text = query.Supplier_Name.ToString()
        txtManufacturer.Text = query.Manufacturer_Name.ToString()
        txtPrice.Text = query.Cost_Per_Unit.ToString()
        txtDiscount.Text = query.Discount_Percentage.ToString()
        txtDescription.Text = query.Part_Description.ToString()
        txtInfo.Text = query.Part_Information.ToString()
        Me.Show()
    End Using
End Sub
```

The issue I am having right now is with the last field, the `txtInfo` TextBox.  You see the `Part_Information` field on the database allows `NULL` values.  So when I go to fill the field when the field is null I am getting a `NullReferenceException`, which is understandable.  However I cannot find a way to get around this exception.

I've tried:

```
If Not IsNothing(query._Part_Information.ToString()) Then
```

As well as

```
If query.Part_Information.Length > 0 Then
```

As If statements to run through first.  But I keep getting the error each time.  So I am confused on how I am suppose to deal with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following options:

- `txtInfo.Text = String.Format("{0}", query.Part_Information)`
- `txtInfo.Text = $"{query.Part_Information}"`  → [$ - String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings)
- `txtInfo.Text = query.Part_Information?.ToString()` → [?. - Null Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

If `query.Part_Information` is null, the first two expressions result in `Sting.Empty` and the last one  result in `Nothing`.